# Internal Server Error (500) when passing ajax request to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, internal-server-error

I am trying to pass data back from my view to the controller via and ajax request.
The request is this:

```
        $("body").on("click", "#AddProduct", function () {
            var id = $("#ProductDrop").val();
            var lookups = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Point.Properties["Lookups"]));
            var body = $("tablePoints tbody")
            var data = JSON.stringify({ "productId": id, "lookupData": lookups });
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/jsonrequest; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: '/Edit/GetProductData',
                data: data,
                success: function (html) { body.append(html) },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("failure");
                    }
            })
        });
```

The controller looks like this:

```
public ViewResult AddRow(string productId, LookupTable lookupData)
{ 
    return View("TableRow",EditPointMethods.AddEmptyProperties(productId,lookupData));
}
```

When I try and pass the data I get an internal server error. However, when I don't pass the data it works. Is there something wrong with how I'm formatting my data? I've checked, and the data is not null and contains all values that I would expect upon the request.

Comment: Have you tried `application/json` as the content type instead of `application/jsonrequest`? What is the backend platform/framework? Isn't the server logging out the errors? (It should.) What is `LookupTable`? What is the value of `var lookups`?

Comment: I am currently running this locally, I can't find anywhere in visual studio that logs a more detailed version of the error. lookups is an object that I use in the model for the view. I essentially need to find an element of data from within lookups that has the same id as product id.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippets that are pasted in question, I think you are not invoking correct MVC controller action.

> url: '/Edit/GetProductData'

But Controller action is this (assuming controller name is EditController):

> public ViewResult AddRow(string productId, LookupTable lookupData)

Try changing url from '/Edit/GetProductData' to '/Edit/**AddRow**'

Also, please post the error if possible.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo from a previous version. I have replaced it with AddRow and I get the same message. the error is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (). I have tried and failed to find a more detailed error message.

Comment: please use contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. If you are able to reach controller action in debug mode, then verify view "TableRow" is at the right place.